# Case statement query

Tags: sql-server

How can this be re-written? somehow not able to make it right. In case statement `THEN` and `ELSE` are the same
would like to change it to a single statement.

```
SELECT    t.status_id status_id, (
CASE WHEN t .status_id NOT IN (SELECT     status_id  FROM  firm_return   WHERE      enabled = 'D' and firm_id=t.firm_id) 

THEN (cl.category_code + '-' + s.status_name)   ELSE cl.category_code + '-' + s.status_name END)  AS status_type
   FROM       bla bla
```

Comment: You have to specify column name immediately after case keyword. Please google once before posting question here --> https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/

Comment: ??? Both alternatives are absolutely the same, so CASE is excess, and this is an equivalent of simple `SELECT t.status_id, cl.category_code + '-' + s.status_name AS status_type FROM ...` (except query falling when `firm_return` table is not accessible).

Comment: Its hard to add firm_return in where due to lot many joins. Any good way to achieve above?

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN` on `firm_return` and in the `SELECT` results have a `IF(firm_return.status_id IS NULL, ..., .....) as status_type` (missed this was sql-server - maybe doesn't have an `IF` expression however `CASE` of a similar concept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example query appears to be incomplete (e.g. your aliases `t` and `cl` don't correspond to anything in the example). Ignoring that for a second and using your example query, this is probably what you're after:

```
SELECT t.status_id AS status_id, cl.category_code + '-' + s.status_name AS status_type
FROM SomeTable AS t
LEFT JOIN firm_return AS s
    ON t.firm_id = s.firm_id
    AND s.enabled = 'D'
... -- The rest of your query logic here (e.g. the table for the cl alias)
```

If you care about `NULLS` and want to handle them with a default value then you can use the `ISNULL()` function around the logic for your `status_type` column like so: `ISNULL(cl.category_code + '-' + s.status_name, 'SomeDefaultValueGoesHere') AS status_type`